# Font icon missing some details if object/path is small (Chrome on Mac)

Tags: css, google-chrome, icons, font-face

I found a bug on Chrome on Mac (as i know), When using custom `@font-face` icon.

When object/path is very small and some size will miss some details.

Im using **IcoMoon** for making my custom font icon

**I testing to make normal and small icon like this :**

[image]

**Then I try to scale font-size and test on Chrome on Mac (57.0.2987.133 (64-bit))**

I got this result :

[image]

You will see the red one some **details is gone** somewhere

Any trick to fix this bug or I have to wait for the updates ?

**Demo :** https://jsfiddle.net/vhhk5vrg/

Answer (score 0):

I think it has do with the transition in font-sizes that the minute details go missing in your icon.

If you just change the state and check the icons, the results look just as fine.

Check this screenshot where I have increased the `font-size` of the smaller red icon.

[image]

Check updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/h2ndq6r4/1/).

**EDIT**

Yes there is some rendering issue at `font-size: 250px` on Chrome on Mac it seems. However, if you zoom in your browser, the details get rendered correctly and are visible.

Check:

[image]

Comment: Try to set font-size on small : 250px; https://jsfiddle.net/h2ndq6r4/2/

Comment: I did, there is some rendering issue. But on zooming in the details are visible again.

Comment: Yeps :( That is bad hehe

Comment: Yeah lol, the behaviour of Chrome on the Mac has always been shady when it comes to the rendering engine!